# Responsive Bootstrap width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I am working with 1045px wrapper width. And I would like to use "twitter Bootstrap" framework.
But i am confused little about **twitter Bootstrap** grid layout.I know, bootstrap wrapper width (responsive) is 1170px. Can i make a wrapper with width of **1045px** ?
Actually, I am very strict on this project. **I have to use 1045 px width**. Can anyone please explain me , is it possible with twitter bootstrap?
Or **is there any other grid framework** for this wrapper width?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

yes you can, and there are several ways to do it. You can customize Bootstrap with SASS or LESS, you can [customize and download your own version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes) of Bootstrap or you can be cool and use the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  whatever
</div>
</div>
```

then in your CSS

```
.container-fluid{max-width:1045px;}
```

this way, you'll keep responsiveness, yes your content won't go any bigger than 1045px, no matter what

Comment: If i change for medium device view with 1045px and keep unchanged for other view(small and large device), is this ok? 

And then i can use,
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    whatever
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: yes. That's why you set MAX-WIDTH. container-fluid is a Bootstap class that will adjust fluidly to any width, is what you can use for full width, full screen layouts. So, no matter if your screen is 10000px or 100px, it will always adjust. by setting a max-width, you're making sure the Bootstrap behavior is maintained BELOW 1045px, but it won't go OVER 1045px, it will simply stop there, so it will be fully responsive up to 1045px and after that, behave just as a fixed size layout

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do that is through http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. When you go down it and customize you can set each container size to whatever you want. Then when you download your custom compiled Bootstrap, it will all be calculated to those widths.

Answer (score -1):

Use boostrap classes  for example  class="container" and in this div class="col-lg-12" for large

```
  <div class ="col-lg-12">
       <div class='container'>
         <div class="col-lg-12">
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container{
        width:1045px;
        }
        }
</style>
```

[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: div class="col-lg-12" for large view. But i am expecting wrapper/container width 1045px .
is this class for this wrapper or container width?

Comment: you use col-lg-12 class in inside class="container"